# Adding HTML inside RaphaelJS elements

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I am creating a circle inside my html page using the following simple code of RaphaelJS. I wanted to ask if there's some way by which I could add my own html inside the circle that I just drew with Raphael.

Adding text inside the object looks possible with absolute positioning, but how do I add my own html such as div, images, or other things **inside the circle** (or a rectangle etc.) preferably without absolute positioning.

Comment: Not really possible unless you are willing to wrangle with `foreignObject` which is not supported in IE.

Comment: @Duopixel: Can you point on how to use foreingObject thingy?

Comment: Actually, I redact my comment: you can't insert new elements into SVG shapes, so `rect`, `circle`, `ellipse` and `path` elements can't have children. You'd still have to position foreignObject with absolute-like positions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RaphaelJS-Infobox](https://github.com/kreynolds/RaphaelJS-Infobox) :

> This is a simple JS helper that automates placement of HTML elements inside of RaphaelJS Containers.

Please test and let me know, this is a simple example:

```
var paper = Raphael("raphael-canvas", 500, 500);
var infobox = new Infobox(paper, {x:10,y:10, width:250, height:250});
infobox.div.html('<p>This is some crazy content that goes inside of that box that will wrap around.</p>');
```

Hope this help enough.

Comment: I'm using RaphaelJS-Infobox and it's great, but I cannot seem to capture 'click' events from within the html that is in the 'div'.  Any suggestions?...